# Auth0 middleware in nodejs (express) gives Error: aggrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, linux, express, auth0

I'm using a middleware in my express API to validate against auth0

```
const checkJwt = jwt({
    // Dynamically provide a signing key based on the kid in the header and the singing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`
    }),

    // Validate the audience and the issuer.
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
    algorithms: ['RS256']
});
```

...

```
  server.use('/api', checkJwt, routes);
```

It works on my local dev-machine but when I run it in production I get:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

I'm running ubuntu 12 in production and mac on dev.

Comment: DON'T WRITE THE `https://`

Comment: Auth fails if I remove it.

Comment: do you have a repo?

Comment: Not public. But there's no mor relevant code than in the question.

Comment: Do `console.log(\`https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json\`)` and check is it not undefined

Comment: There may be a problem of not getting Any token from client side because of invalid parsing of body. or may be cross origin, There is agreat tutorial available at  ==>  https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/application/server-api/api-implementation-nodejs

Comment: output of your-- https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json should be look like ==> https://sandrino.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: @ponury-kostek you just saved my afternoon... I had defined ALL of my other AUTH0_... with a zero symbol, but for _DOMAIN the '0' in AUTH0 was a f#%king capital 'o' ... I have shamed my family lol

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you forgot to setup `AUTH0_DOMAIN` environment variable on the production system.

Your code is correct according to example from [github](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/tree/master/examples/express-demo) ,

but in this example there is section how to run this code with lot of environment variables setup.

`DEBUG=express,jwks JWKS_HOST=https://my-authz-server AUDIENCE=urn:my-resource-server ISSUER=https://my-authz-server/ node server.js`.

Please check your production configuration before starting an app.

Answer (score 4):

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

This is a basic internet transport protocol error  arising when the server address requested for can not be connected to. 
Can be a very simple bug, can be something entirely complex :

- no internet connection on host system
- lack of permission for host system to send request
- lack of permission for client system to accept request (like if part pf a vpc blocked from public domain)

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:443

- the *undefined  undefined*  shows that the url passed to which the system is trying to connect to is not defined.

I think the problem is with parsing as the codeblock shown is commenting out the uri you are providing, try this please  :

```
const uri  = "https:\/\/"+${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}+"/.well-known/jwks.json"
const checkJwt = jwt({
// Dynamically provide a signing key based on the kid in the header and the singing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: uri
}),

// Validate the audience and the issuer.
audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
algorithms: ['RS256']
});
```

Similar edit for issuer in the jwt options

Answer (score 0):

Ensure AUTH0_DOMAIN env variable does not have the https:// prefix.

This caught me and was not clear from the Auth0 docs.

Comment: This was my case too!!!